# (git): How to bring specific commit from upstream branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit, rebase

I have this (git repo):

```
A--B--C--D ->master
   \--E    ->dev
```

And I want to bring only commit `D` to branch `dev` (`D` doesn't depend on `C`), so that:

```
A--B--C--D  ->master
   \--E--D' ->dev
```

But D' shouldn't get added to master after a merge:

```
A--B--C--D--E' ->master
   \--E--D'/   ->dev
```

This is because I want to bring only a file update without having to pollute `dev` with new files that `C` (which represents another, big merge) adds.
I'm guessing I need to use `git rebase`, but I can't guess how.

Answer (score 13):

You want to use [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). I'll assume your remote is named "origin" (but substitute the real name of the remote repo for "origin"). I'll assume you have two local branches also named `master` and `dev`. I'll assume commit D is on `origin/dev`. You can cherry-pick D with the following:

```
$ git fetch origin             # Assuming the upstream remote's name is "origin"
$ git checkout dev             # Check out your local "dev" branch
$ git cherry-pick $COMMIT_D    # Replace "COMMIT_D" with the hash for commit D
```

Now you'll only have the changes from commit D in `dev`.

Answer (score -1):

Use [git cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) *updated with working link*